# DELETE in Spring RestTemplate with HttpEntity<List>

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-rest

I don't know why my code is not working, I've tried with Postman and works fine:

[image: WORKS FINE]

But with `RestTemplate` I can´t get a response while it´s using the same endpoint... .

```
ResponseEntity<String> responseMS  = template.exchange(notificationRestService, HttpMethod.DELETE, new HttpEntity<NotificationRestDTO[]>(arrNotif), String.class);
```

I've tried with `List` instead `Array[]`

When i made a `PUT` request it´s works fine but with one object:

```
ResponseEntity<String> responseMS = template.exchange(notificationRestService, HttpMethod.PUT, new HttpEntity<NotificationRestDTO>(notificationDTO), String.class);
```

Any help?? Thanks!!

Comment: You should use `DELETE` as an http method with resttemplate too?

Comment: Something like :  `new RestTemplate().delete ( uri,  params )`.

Comment: @MouadELFakir `restTemplate.exchange()` should also work. The `delete()` API does not allow you to send a request body as far as I know.

Comment: Miguel, can you tell us what the result is of the `RestTemplate.exchang()` call. Does it throw an exception or something else?

Comment: @g00glen00b i only get a 400 null from SoapUI, in code goes thwrow Spring classes and i cant see anything

Comment: Are you on JDK 1.8?

Comment: With GET, POST and UPDATE it works fine, it should be the list of the body or anything

Comment: Please see this bug: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12361 If you're on JDK 1.7, it will not work.

Comment: @Strelok i´m in java 8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comments it became clear that you're expecting it to return a **400 Bad Request** response. `RestTemplate` will see these as "client errors" and it will throw a [`HttpClientErrorException`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/HttpClientErrorException.html).

If you want to handle cases like this, you should catch this exception, for example:

```
try {
    ResponseEntity<String> responseMS  = template.exchange(notificationRestService, HttpMethod.DELETE, new HttpEntity<NotificationRestDTO[]>(arrNotif), String.class);
} catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
    String message = ex.getResponseBodyAsString();
}
```

In this case (since you expect a `String`), you can use the [`getResponseBodyAsString()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestClientResponseException.html#getResponseBodyAsString--) method.

---

The `ResponseEntity` will only contain the data in case your request can be executed successfully (2xx status code, like 200, 204, ...). So, if you only expect a message to be returned if the request was not successfully, you can actually do what Mouad mentioned in the comments and you can use the `delete()` method of the `RestTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just as an update `TestRestTemplate.delete(...)` is still `void` ... I don't understand why is there no `deleteForEntity` as for all the other HttpMethods, just with `response.body = null`

Comment: Actually, the same seems to be true for `RestTemplate.patch(...)` as well